# Spring SAML2 IdP certificate update

Tags: spring, saml-2.0, spring-saml

Our IdP is updating certificate in their IdP metadata.

They are offering one month period in which both old and new certificate will be valid so that we can switch to new certificate.

The issue is, that anytime they updated certificate, we have to redeploy IdP metadata containing new certificate and that includes downtime that we would like to avoid if possible (server restart).

My question is:

is there the possibility to switch to new IdP metadata file without server restart (Java app running in Tomcat 7)

Alternatively, is there the possibility to use 2 metadata files for same IdP, one with new, one with old certificate, and to switch in runtime to new one?

Answer (score 2):

You can include both signature certificates in the same IDP metadata. Spring SAML will be trying to verify signature on an incoming message using all available certificates, until it finds a match or fails. Two files for the same IdP won't work.

You can use the *org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider*, which will automatically reload metadata when the file its configuration points to gets updated - without application restart.

Answer (score 0):

For any metadata file update/modification, using `FileSystem Watcher` service, I destroyed the existing `MetadataProvider` and created the new one. And it reloaded the IDP certificate immediately. `FilesystemMetadataProvider` was also working fine but one can use the destroy method from `AbstractMetadataProvider` class to reload the certificates even when using `ResourceBackedMetadataProvider`.